# Is The @PrimaryKey annotation field in Android not considered as a separate field?

Tags: android, android-room, one-to-one

I understand that the @Embedded annotation is used when we want to combine several fields which can then be represented into a single object. In the Android Developers documentation, within the [one-to-one relationships section](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one) of the **Define Relationships Between Objects** document, we find this code:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long userId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

@Entity
public class Library {
    @PrimaryKey public long libraryId;
    public long userOwnerId;
}
```

In the next section, about modeling the one-to-one relationships, there's this code which says:

```
public class UserAndLibrary {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userOwnerId"
    )
    public Library library;
}
```

What I don't understand is why are we using the @Embedded annotation just for the User class? The Library class also has several fields and we do need to combine them as well, right? Or is it because the @PrimaryKey field isn't considered as a separate field?

Comment: I can't explain the "why", but it's clear that Room doesn't need the @Embedded annotation to generate the correct implementation, and actually disallows it with error message "A field can be annotated with only one of the following: ColumnInfo,Embedded,Relation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Embedded annotation is used when we want to combine several fields which can then be represented into a single object

Yes, that's correct

But converse statement is not correct:

> If you want to combine several fields into a single object you SHOULD ONLY use @Embedded annotation in Room

There is another method in Room how you can achieve this "combination" - with `@Relation`. But except "combining fields into a single object" `@Relation` makes some additional work - internally it changes your simplified DAO query:

```
select * from user
```

, so you don't need to write "JOIN" with another table. But this "additional" work makes sense ONLY for the second table, that's why first object - with `@Embedded` and the second - with `@Relation`.

You can, for example not to use @Relation in your example:

```
public class UserAndLibrary {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Embedded public Library library;
}
```

But to get needed result in your query you have to explicitly use both tables and "JOIN" them or use "IN":

```
select * from user left join library on user.userId = library.userOwnerId
```

Comment: Got it. This makes much more sense. Basically, the @Relation annotation is being used with the second object to simplify the DAO query.